# Firestore - React JS realtime listener of a collection

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

Dears,
Please advise on how can I save the output from Firestore's request (PLEASE READ THE COMMENTS IN THE CODE BELOW):

```
const firestore = firebase.firestore();
export const fetchedTickets = []; //I want to store the fetched tickets from a collection "tickets" and use it somewhere else

//Starting to listen changes in Tickets collection
const unsubscriberForTicketsListener = firestore
  .collection("tickets")
  .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
      if (change.type === "added") {
        // console.log("Added Ticket: ", change.doc.data());
        fetchedTickets.push(change.doc.data());
      }
      if (change.type === "modified") {
        console.log("Edited Ticket: ", change.doc.data());
      }
      if (change.type === "removed") {
        console.log("Remvoed Ticket: ", change.doc.data());
      }
    });

    console.log(fetchedTickets) //From here, I can reach the fetched tickets, but I can't return this array, or do something valuable with it (store, for example)
  });

console.log(fetchedTickets) //Here, fetchedTickets is just an empty array, so I can't return it's value to use it in a different file, for example
```

Comment: This is the expected behavior. Since data is loaded from Firestore asynchronously, all code that needs the data needs to be inside the callback (like your first `console.log(fetchedTickets)`) is. While code outside the callback can access the same variables, it typically runs before the data is loaded - unless you yourself ensure it runs at the right time (by using promises or something like RxJS).

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but you might want to keep in mind that text typed in ALL CAPS is typically perceived as yelling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. Since data is loaded from Firestore asynchronously, all code that needs the data needs to be inside the callback (like your first `console.log(fetchedTickets)`) is.

While code outside the callback can access the same variables, it typically runs before the data is loaded - unless you yourself ensure it runs at the right time (by using promises or something like RxJS).

Also see:

- [Not able to iterate over array of users pulled from firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57477816/not-able-to-iterate-over-array-of-users-pulled-from-firebase/57478638#57478638)
- [Array of JSON object is not empty but cannot iterate with foreach, show zero length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57147692/array-of-json-object-is-not-empty-but-cannot-iterate-with-foreach-show-zero-len/57148528#57148528)
- [Firestore onSnapshot returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55950029/firestore-onsnapshot-returns-undefined)

And more from this [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D%5Bjavascript%5D+asynchronous).

Comment: Thanks Frank.
Yes, I do understand that, but my question is - How can I take the fetched data out of this listener's funciton

Comment: As explained in my answer and the ones linked: this is not about accessing it in a certain scope, but about **when** you access it. By the time your second `console.log(fetchedTickets)` runs, the data hasn't been loaded yet. The way to make it wait is with a promise, but at that point you might as well use `get()` instead of `onSnapshot`.

Comment: Yeah, but get() will return the data once, and I want to put a listener so I can handle all the changes in the firestore in the real time

Comment: That's perfectly what `onSnapshot` is for. But that does mean all code that uses the data must be inside the `onSnapshot` callback, as otherwise it won't run at the right time.