# firestore getting doc data issue

Tags: reactjs, firebase, use-effect

I trying to get the url of an image from firebase firestore, the upload goes successfully, but when I try to get the image and display it, it gives me this error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'doc.push')

This is the method how I get datas:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const result = db.collection("homeBackground").doc("bg_img").onSnapshot(snap => {
            const doc = snap.doc;
            setImages(doc.push(doc => doc.data()))
        });
        return result;
    }, []);
```

This is how I display the image:

```
{
    images.push((image) => {
         return (
            <img src={image.imageUrl} alt=""/>
                )
           })
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore onSnapshot returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55950029/firestore-onsnapshot-returns-undefined)

Comment: Doc is a documentSnapshot and contains createdBy and imageUrl. how are you accessing the fields? Also, you're returning result *after* the closure so that code will return result, which will not be populated yet (Firestore is asynchronous)

Answer (score 1):

`onSnapshot()` is a kind of asynchronous Observable method. You need to check are data exist then assign to any thing you want.

```js
.onSnapshot(snap => {
            if(snap.exists()) { // Some methods returns object with .exist value/function.
               setImages(snap.data())
            }
        });
```

`onSnapshot(snapshoot: QuerySnapshot<DocumentData> | DocumentSnapshot<DocumentData> => ...)` This is what you get depending on on what you wariong on you can get generic object of querysnapshot or DocumentSnapshot.

This method will trigger when data will change in database. It returns unsubscription which you can invoke and stop observing database changes.

```js
const unsubscription = db.collection("homeBackground").doc("bg_img").onSnapshot(snap => ...);

// later in time
unsubscription() // this will stop invoke method above.
```

Comment: don't work... if I do the console log it gives me correct data..
.onSnapshot(doc => {
            console.log(doc.data())
        });

Comment: @GabrieleSabatino How about now ? I don't know what kind of object you need in setImage() function.

Comment: @GabrieleSabatino Edited check are it works.

Comment: TypeError: snap.exists is not a function. (In 'snap.exists()', 'snap.exists' is true)

Comment: @GabrieleSabatino I am using firebase 9+ i have method no variable.

Comment: I have 9.2.0 @Mises

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241072/discussion-between-mises-and-gabriele-sabatino).